# How to handle non-conflicting branches that break once merged

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

(The code examples below are fabrications to demonstrate the issue with `git`. Please ignore them otherwise.)

Suppose I have a file `source.js`:

```js
function maker(str) {
  return `Hello ${str}!`;
}

function base(str) {
  console.log(maker(str));
}

base("world");
```

I have branch A with this diff:

```
diff --git a/source.js b/source.js
index 2eb7de1..6c49051 100644
--- a/source.js
+++ b/source.js
@@ -6,4 +6,9 @@ function base(str) {
   console.log(maker(str));
 }
 
+function next(str) {
+  console.log(`${maker(str)}`);
+}
+
 base("world");
+next("world");
```

I also have branch B with this diff:

```
diff --git a/source.js b/source.js
index 2eb7de1..ecb08f9 100644
--- a/source.js
+++ b/source.js
@@ -1,9 +1,5 @@
-function maker(str) {
-  return `Hello ${str}!`;
-}
-
 function base(str) {
-  console.log(maker(str));
+  console.log(`Hello ${str}!`);
 }
 
 base("world");
```

Both branches are making self-consistent changes. Either can be merge to `main`, and both can be merged without merge conflicts. However if both are merged, the script no longer runs.

In my specific situation, I cannot merge locally and push to `main` for security reasons, so it's not possible to merge and test manually.

If I'm using a hosting service (like Github or Gitlab), how do I make sure that merging a set of PRs won't run into this issue?

Comment: Can't you merge A into B (or vice versa) locally and test locally? I also don't understand why you can't merge into `main` locally and test that.

Comment: You might not be able to push to master, but you can merge locally on master, test everything you want, then push that tested state to a temp branch, which can be the source of a pull request to master.

Comment: I'm on a team of roughly 30 engineers, and we're merging multiple times per day. Sadly, our test suite takes ~20 min to run (and is required to pass before we can merge), so it's possible to create a branch fresh from main and open a PR for it, and then have another PR get merged before the test suite finishes (not to mention any reviews).

Comment: Other than forcing the pipeline to rerun the build and tests for ALL PRs after each merge (which I am not sure is possible in your case), I don't think this can be solved.

Comment: @NoahBogart Yes, this is typically the way to avoid multiple builds by regrouping multiple features on a single branch then triggering a single build with all the changes, rather than rebuilding for each. *(Side note: 30 engineers? You might want to consider picking the most experienced in git an make him/her a release manager, which role would be to smooth things up)*